# Authentication for a webservice with "real" clients and server clients

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

We have an application which are deployed as instances for our customers. These instances then talk with our billing and management web service using a REST API.

Here's a diagram:

[image]

The `Billing and management service` will never be publicly available and will only be able to us when we build the code for `Customer Instance`. Since this is a server to server interface, I feel that `2 legged OAuth` is the best choice.

The `Customer instance` also contains an API (also RESTful).Third party developers can build apps for it, so we will be using `3 legged OAuth` and follow Facebook's model.

However, we also want to be able to allow `Billing/Management` to access that API (on the customer instance too).

- How should we authenticate this area? Should we use 2 legged OAuth as well?
- Will running 2 legged OAuth and 3 legged OAuth together on the same API endpoint cause security implications?

We are planning to use OAuth 2.0 and all the parts, services are written in PHP.